# How to Convert String to Dataset

Tags: java, json

I am getting a value in Json Format and  Assigned it into a String. 
In Java, How can i Convert a String Value into a Data Set of Ignition. And
how do i Convert a Json Object to Data Set?

```
postRequest.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
HttpEntity entity;
entity = new StringEntity(mapper.writeValueAsString(context), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
postRequest.setEntity(entity); 
CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = null; 
httpResponse = httpClient.execute(postRequest); 
String response = null;
response = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
AnalysisData = response;
Dataset dataset = Dataset.class.cast(vAnalysisData);
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post your code?

Comment: I added the code from your comment to question. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking new questions

Answer (score 0):

Java does not handle Json parsing on it's own. You must import a third party Json library. Google Gson is the one I use. Here is the [link](https://github.com/google/gson). Once the Json response is parsed into Json Elements, then you can add each element to the DataSet.

Share part of your code, so that it will be easier to help.